# Sessions being reset on page reload/refresh?

Tags: php, session, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, lamp

I am using AWS with Ubuntu LAMP stack. I usually just used MAMP on my Mac to test things and use a managed hosting service such as GoDaddy, so this is my first time using AWS. My old developer setup AWS for me, so I have since then taken over.

My code is working perfectly on MAMP, although failing to work on AWS.

When a user attempts to login, I call my RESTful API written in PHP to validate the login and set a session variable if successful. I then refresh the page and check if the session is set, and if it is set I load a different php file.

**This is my entire `index.php` file:**

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['user_login_status'] == 1) {
    include("app.php");
} else {
    include("login.php");
}
```

During the refresh, it seems as if my session variables are being destroyed/reset. I have tried `echo`ing the session value before the `if` statement, although it is always blank.

**Things I have made sure of:**

- I am setting `session_start()` at the very top of my php file, so
  that can't be the problem.
- I connected via SSH to access to `php.ini` file and checked that
  `session.gc_maxlifetime` is `1440`

Just seems odd that it works on MAMP and not on my AWS server.

Answer (score 1):

I had more or less the same problem.
It is the PHP version installed in the server who make the bug.
To solve it, just do it like this

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['user_login_status'] !== 1) {
    include("login.php");
} else {
    include("app.php");
}
```

OR

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1) {
     include("login.php);
} else {
     include("app.php");
}
```

OR

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['user_login_status'] === 1) {
     include("app.php");
} else {
     include("login.php);
}
```